# Исполнять вводимую пользователем функцию

Tags: python, функции, классы

есть очень много функций (точнее методов класса но думаю это не так важно), и когда пользователь вводит название функции то она должна исполняться. Понимаю что можно заифать но это очень долго. Уверен что возможно как то подругому реализовать. Вопрос - Как.

```
def f1(arg1,arg2):
   pass
def f2():
   pass
def f3():
   pass

user_input = input()
while user_input != 'exit':
   user_input = input()

   #doing entered func
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` или `exec`. Первый возвращает результат, а второй - нет. И еще проверяйте на возможность вызова этих функций с конкретным кодом. Мало ли какую дыру в безопасности откроете.

### Пример

```
""" @file 53d2b4c8dc804d16a8a83ea69dad14bb.py
"""
functions = list("abcdefghj")
for function in functions:
    exec(f"def {function}(): return 'Hello from {function}!'")

# Печатаем все доступные функции:
print(*[" * " + x for x in globals() if callable(globals()[x])], sep='\n')

cin = ' '
while cin != '':
    cin = input("Function: ")
    if cin in functions:
        print(eval(cin + "()"))
    else:
        print(f">:( '{cin}'?")
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо за ответ. Сейчас все сделаю и постараюсь так же исключить взлом XSS атакой.